# Combining Predicates in F#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, composition

Is there a standard way of logically combining predicates in F#?
For example, let's say I have `isCar x` and `isBlue x` then I want something that gives me:

```
let isBlueCar x = isCar x && isBlue x
```

But using some sort of composition, rather than invocation, maybe like:

```
let isBlueCar x = isCar && isBlue
```

Preferably, that something would be able to accept a large/arbitrary number of predicates.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could define a combinator.

```
let (<&>) f g = (fun x -> f x && g x)
```

then do

```
let isBlueCar = isCar <&> isBlue
```

Comment: ... and it really is that easy, huh? I love F#.

Comment: @GregRos - check out FParsec (http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec), a beautifully crafted parsing library built using the combinators approach :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
let meetsAll preds = preds |> Seq.fold (fun p q x -> p x && q x) (fun _ -> true)
// or     let meetsAll preds x = preds |> Seq.forall (fun p -> p x)
```

as in

```
let isEven x = x%2 = 0
let isDiv5 x = x%5 = 0
let isDiv7 x = x%7 = 0

let div257 = meetsAll [isEven; isDiv5; isDiv7]

for i in 1..100 do
    if div257 i then
        printfn "%d" i
```

There is no standard library function for it, but there are a plethora of one-liners you can define on your own, as evidenced by the answers here.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like the following:

```
let predicates = [isCar; isBlue]
let isBlueCar x = predicates |> List.forall (fun predicate -> predicate x)
```

More generally:

```
let combinePredicates predicates =
    fun x -> predicates |> List.forall (fun predicate -> predicate x)

let isBlueCar = combinePredicates [isCar;isBlue]
```

Comment: Or in point-free syntax: `let isBlueCar = (|>) >> flip List.forall predicates`

Comment: @RamonSnir Where is `flip` defined though?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I don't think it's built-in, you need to define it yourself: `let flip f a b = f b a`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
> let (&&<) a b x = a x && b x

val ( &&< ) : ('a -> bool) -> ('a -> bool) -> 'a -> bool

> let isBlueCar = isCar &&< isBlue

val isBlueCar : (int -> bool)
```