# How to cleanly hand parameters from function to function (like composition)

Tags: .net, f#, fold, function-composition

```
let myFunc x y =
    List.fold (&&) true [func1 x y; func2 x y]
```

I don't know all the different operators and techniques in F#, but was hoping I could just plop some operator in place of "x y" for func1 and func2 to indicate to them "Just take my parameters" almost like how composition has implicit parameter pass through.

Alternatively, if someone can think of a much more straightforward and clean way of doing this that gets rid of the need for my function to hand it's parameters in, let me know.

Also, if this is just not possible which seems entirely likely, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10854010/162396

Comment: I see the S combinator there as well, interesting to learn where it's really useful, is for composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a nice way to thread the parameters of `myfunc` to the parameters of `func1` and `func2`. However, your example is perhaps a bit over-simplified, because you could just write:

```
let myfunc x y = 
  func1 x y && func2 x y
```

I suppose that in reality, you have a larger number of functions and then using `fold` makes a good sense. In that case, you could use `fold` to combine the *functions* rather than using it to combine the *results*.

If I simplify the problem a little and assume that `func1` and `func2` take the two arguments as a tuple (instead of taking them as two separate arguments), then you can write something like this:

```
let func1 (a, b) = true
let func2 (a, b) = true

let myfunc = List.fold (fun f st a -> f a && st a) (fun _ -> true) [ func1; func2 ]
```

Now you do not need to pass the parameters around explicitly (to `func1` and `func2`), but the arguments of `fold` got a bit more complicated. I think that's fine, because you need to write that just once (and it is quite readable this way).

However, if you're fan of the point-free style (or just want to see how far you could get), you can define a few helper functions and then write the code as follows:

```
/// Given a value, returns a constant function that always returns that value
let constant a _ = a
/// Takes an operation 'a -> b -> c' and builds a function that
/// performs the operation on results of functions    
let lift2 op f g x = op (f x) (g x)

let myfunc2  = List.fold (lift2 (&&)) (constant true) [ ffunc1; ffunc2 ]
```

If you do not need arbitrary number of functions, then I'd simplify the code and not use `fold` at all. If you need to do that, then I think your version is very readable and not too long. The examples I wrote in this answer show that you can avoid passing the parameters by hand, but it makes the code a bit cryptic.

Comment: I figured if I added another layer of indirection somehow I could get it to work. Yes I recognize that it can be simplified as your first example but I've for more functions to test. Thanks for this, I'll have to sit on it to understand how the parameters are being threaded into place with your example..

Comment: I see the S and the K combinators in there.. I really wonder how people know when to use those. As much as I can use them, the only combinator I've seen myself recognize a place for was B..

Comment: So my takeaway here, it can be done, but becomes a mess. Too specific an implementation to be reused, and too much to be implemented for a single use case, so stick with my approach.